# Spring Boot Admin not working after deployment in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-admin

We are trying to deploy our newly created Spring Admin UI for monitoring purposes.

We followed this tutorial to do so [A Guide to Spring Boot Admin| Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-admin#:%7E:text=Spring%20Boot%20Admin%20is%20a,the%20Spring%20Boot%20Actuator%20endpoints)

There is no additional bean configuration there. Is this the problem?

`$sudo java -jar admin.jar` is working fine. But when we try to deploy it in tomcat, we are getting this error:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Message The requested resource [/admin/] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.36
```

Can anybody please help?
Thanks in advance.